# Weighting elements of a matrix based on a coefficient dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have got this coefficient table under the form of a `dataframe`:

```
coefficient_table <- data.frame("less_than_1" = c( 1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.025, 0.010, 0.005, 0.001),
                            "1-5" = c(0.500, 1.000, 0.200, 0.050, 0.020, 0.010, 0.002),
                            "5-20" = c(0.10, 0.20, 1.00, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01),
                            "20-50" = c(0.025, 0.050, 0.250, 1.000, 0.400, 0.200, 0.040),
                            "50-100" = c(0.010, 0.020, 0.10, 0.400, 1.00, 0.500, 0.100),
                            "100-500" = c(0.005, 0.010, 0.050, 0.200, 0.500, 1.000, 0.200),
                            "more_than_500" = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.010, 0.040, 0.100, 0.200, 1.000))
```

I would like to apply it to a matrix that has 7 dimensions that has the same variables as my coefficient `dataframe`. For now this is how it looks:

```
A <- data.frame("less_than_1" = c(0,0,1,0), "1-5" = c(1,0,0,0), "5-20" = c(0,0,0,0), 
                   "20-50" = c(0,1,0,1), "50-100" = c(0,0,0,0), "100-500" = c(0,0,0,0), 
                 "more_than_500" = c(0,0,0,0))
A <- as.matrix(A)

   less_than_1   1-5   5-20   20-50   50-100   100-500   more_than_500
1      0          1      0      0       0         0           0
2      0          0      0      1       0         0           0 
3      1          0      0      0       0         0           0
4      0          0      0      1       0         0           0
```

I would like however to use my coefficient matrix to weight the elements of the matrix based on the formula I've used to create the coefficients, namely: min(BudgetRange1,BudgetRange2) / max(BudgetRange1,BudgetRange2) .

The first row has for example a budget of "1-5", the respective column should therefore take value 1. The other columns should take their respective value based on the same column "1-5" of the coefficient matrix (A).

```
table_z

  less_than_1   1-5   5-20   20-50   50-100   100-500   more_than_500
1     0.5        1     0.2    0.05    0.02     0.01         0.002
2     0.025     0.05   0.25   1       0.4      0.2          0.04
3     1         0.5    0.1    0.025   0.01     0.005        0.001
4     0.025     0.05   0.25   1       0.4      0.2          0.04
```

Anyone knows how? Thanks for reading so far

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me how you mix the coefficients data.frame with data.frame A to obtain your last data.frame... could you please elaborate your example a little more ?

Comment: Maybe I've confused you with too many irrelevant details, sorry. In the final table (table_z), I want the row to equal the respective vector found in coefficient_table. For example in row 1, all columns equal 0 except "1-5", which equals to 1. Because "1-5" equals to 1, I want R to look at coefficient_table, take the respective "1-5" vector and fill the other elements of table_z with the vector's values (less_than_1 equals to 0.5, 5-20 equals to 0.2, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the columns (i.e. 'less_than_1', '1-5', '5-20' ...) are exaclty in the same order for both `coefficient_table` and `A` , you can use matrix multiplication :

```
Z <- as.matrix(A)%*%as.matrix(coefficient_table)
> Z
     less_than_1  1-5 5-20 20-50 50-100 100-500 more_than_500
[1,]       0.500 1.00 0.20 0.050   0.02   0.010         0.002
[2,]       0.025 0.05 0.25 1.000   0.40   0.200         0.040
[3,]       1.000 0.50 0.10 0.025   0.01   0.005         0.001
[4,]       0.025 0.05 0.25 1.000   0.40   0.200         0.040

# where Z is a matrix, you can convert to data.frame if you need it :
table_z <- as.data.frame(Z)
```